# How to Destory kendo window popup in close action in kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, window

Am using kendo window for popup, when click on close anchor tag, it will close model window, but it sits in DOM. I wanted to destroy the model pop up. Below is my code. I tried `this.destory()` in close action, but it is not destroying. Please help me.

```
var selectRowsDialog = $("#select-Rows-dialog").kendoWindow({
            width: "800px",
            title: "Select rows",
            autoOpen: false,
            closable: true,
            modal: true,
            visible: false,
            close: function () { 
            },       
        }).data("kendoWindow").center().open();
```

Comment: `this.destory()`? Did you also try `this.destroy()`?

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to [`destroy()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#methods-destroy) the Window instance in its [`deactivate`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#events-deactivate) event. In this way you will not lose the closing animation.

```
<div id="window">Kendo UI Window here</div>

<script>
  $("#window").kendoWindow({
    deactivate: function(e) {
      e.sender.destroy();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: i use `this.destroy();` in the deactivate event.. im guessing this works too?

Comment: Yes, it does. It’s a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#select-Rows-dialog").data("kendoWindow").close();
```

Comment: Hi thx for your reply.

I have tried this $("#select-Rows-dialog").data("kendoWindow").close(); in close function but I was getting error. "Maximum call stack size exceeded". I have tried this.destory() already, but after closing kendowindow and tried to open Cannot read property 'center' of undefined and Cannot read property 'table' of undefined errors. Please help me

Comment: Have you checked if your script references are proper? A while back, I resolved the issue of "Cannot read property 'center' of undefined" by changing the reference of  kendo.all.min.js.

Comment: Yes they are proper and working fine with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

@Kranthi, that happens when you make a infinite loop in javascript.
So, probably you are calling the kendoWindow.close method in the Deactive event handler. 
And he is getting stuck there, because when he calls close events que also calls deactivate, so there you go that "Maximum call stack size exceeded".
There are two options to either destroy your window or clean totally your model. (There is probably a third, which is to erase the iframe from within of the kendoWindow and create it back, not my best choice) so:
1.On your load page method always fill empty your model or well, how ever you have it handled just, send it empty if it goes empty, but litarally like

```
    Model.id = ""
```

2.On close event of your window call the method destroy(), but when you have to open again your window you'll have to call everything back from the begining, like creating one more time your controls. Thats up to you.

I had to use both constantly, because i have a big, big, app which has like hundreds of PopUps and using kendoWindow let them open if you don't destroy them.